# How to multiply or divide two Series in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, series, divide

I have a dataset like this. The actual dataset is much larger though.

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':["Tom","Andy","Joseph","Joe","Mary","Alexa","Chris","Jessica","Jimmy","Andrea","George","Bruce","Will","Eric","Leonard","Ryan","Megan","Michael","Sara"],\
                  "City":["NY","DC","LAX","NY","DC","DC","SF","SD","NY","SF","SD","DC","LAX","SF","LAX","NY","SF","PDX","FL"],\
                  'Car':["Ford","Ford","TOYOTA","GM","GM","Honda","GM","Porsche","Tesla","TOYOTA","Tesla","Tesla","Honda","GM","Nissan","Porsche","Nissan","Ford","Tesla"]})
```

First, I want to calculate the actual frequency of the "City" and "Car" combination and did this.

```
df_City_Car_actual=data1.groupby(["City","Car"]).size()
df_City_Car_actual
```

Then I want to calculate the expected frequency of the "City" and "Car" combination.
So I did this first.

```
df_City=data1.groupby("City").size()
df_City
df_Car=data1.groupby("Car").size()
df_Car
```

Then I want to multiply df_City and df_Car and show the expected frequency of City x Car.
For example, "DC" frequency is 4 in the df_City and "Ford" frequency is 3 in the df_Car.
Therefore, the DC x Ford expected frequency will be 4x3=12.

I tried this but did not work

```
df_City_Car_expected=df_City*df_Car
df_City_Car_expected
```

Finally, I want to divide the df_City_Car_actual by the df_City_Car_expected so that the final data will be normalized.
Is there a good way to do this?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is by using the `numpy` "outer product" function, as such:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.outer(df_City.values, df_Car.values), index=df_City.index, columns=df_Car.index)
```

Which gives:

```
Car   Ford  GM  Honda  Nissan  Porsche  TOYOTA  Tesla
City                                                 
DC      12  16      8       8        8       8     16
FL       3   4      2       2        2       2      4
LAX      9  12      6       6        6       6     12
NY      12  16      8       8        8       8     16
PDX      3   4      2       2        2       2      4
SD       6   8      4       4        4       4      8
SF      12  16      8       8        8       8     16
```